# WebClient usage with WebSphere MQ Exposed Queue on http "web service"

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to consume a MQ queue exposed in a http url. This is the way is invoked:

```
http://www.example.com/InquCustomers?<data><id>12345</id></data>
```

If I copy/paste that url in the IE, the method returns the correct XML back with all the info.

But if I use the WebClient class or the HttpRequest class to get the string, always the XML specified in the URL (using an Uri object too) are escaped before is sent, and the MQ method returns an error, with my XML parameter escaped.

```
"%3cdata%3e%3cid%3e12345%3c%2fid%3e%3c%2fdata%3e"
```

Example:

```
 string su = "http://www.example.com/InquCustomers?";
 string data = "<data><id>12345</id></data>";
 string res = string.Empty;
 using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
 {
     res = wc.DownloadString(su + data);
     //also res = wc.DownloadString(new Uri(su+data));
 }
```

There's a way to turn off that auto escaping feature or **invoke that URL "as" an IE browser from my app**? Also I can't "touch" the MQ method